# Elliptic curve of order $p = 2q + 1$

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

Does anyone know an example of an Elliptic Curve of caracteristic $p$ ($E_p$) that has a point generator $G$ that generates a subgroup of order $q$, with $p$, $q$ being prime numbers and $p = 2q + 1$?

Comment: Possible duplicate [elliptic curves of prime order](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44397/18298)

Comment: I suspect that any such curve would be supersingular, and so (unless you're doing isogenies) wouldn't be a good idea for crypto

Comment: @fgrieu: I believe he's talking about the characteristic

Comment: @fgrieu: With $p$ I mean the modulus of the field of the Elliptic Curve. Is that the characteristic?

Comment: A finite elliptic curve is based on some finite field $GF(p^k)$.  The characteristic of the curve is actually defined to be $p$; however since you have $k=1$, that's the same.  fgrieu was confused because 'order' is more typically used to mean 'the size of the (sub)group' (which is how you used it the second time)

Comment: @kelalaka: not a dupe: that linked question asks for an Elliptic curve with a generator of prime order $q$ to replace multiplication in $\Bbb Z^∗_{2q+1}$, but does not require a curve of characteristic $p$ like the present (modified) question does.

Comment: @poncho: the properties of the curve are mentioned in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274342367_Elliptic_curve_ElGamal_Threshold-based_Key_Management_Scheme_against_Compromise_of_Distributed_RSUs_for_VANETs (section 2.3 Elliptic Curve ElGamal Threshold Cryptosystem). Am I reading it right and, if so, why aren't there curves with those properties?

Comment: You're not reading it right - the requirement that $p = 2q+1$ applies only to section 2.2 - for section 2.3, all that is required is that $p$ and $q$ be prime.  That's common to (almost) all uses of elliptic curves in cryptography.

Comment: @poncho: so Elliptic Curve Threshold ElGamal doesn't need $p=2q+1$ to work? How can this work, then: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77431/elgamal-threshold-cryptosystem